# How to serve webpack files?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have created a vendor.js and mainbundle.js through using the dllreferenceplugin. This is the command that I am running:

```
 "npm run build:dll && webpack --config=webpack.dev.config.js --watch --progress"
```

In the console I can see:

```
Hash: bad1c37262433a8e91d4                                                                                                             
Version: webpack 3.10.0                                                                                                                
Time: 14767ms                                                                                                                          
        Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names                                                                                  
dll.vendor.js  244 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor                                                                                       
   [0] dll vendor 12 bytes {0} [built]                                                                                                 
   [1] ./vendors.js 89 bytes {0} [built]                                                                                               
   [5] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]                                                                               
   [6] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]                                                                               
    + 5 hidden modules                                                                                                                 
  0% compiling                                                                                                                         
Webpack is watching the files…                                                                                                         

Hash: 83dc1ce27d7783871347                                                                                                             
Version: webpack 3.10.0                                                                                                                
Time: 5226ms                                                                                                                           
     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names                                                                                    
mainapp.js  3.66 kB       0  [emitted]  app                                                                                            
   [0] ./client/app/app.js 357 bytes {0} [built]                                                                                       
   [1] delegated ../node_modules/angular/index.js from dll-reference vendor 42 bytes {0} [built]                                       
    + 1 hidden module
```

How do I configure webpack-dev-server to serve these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `devServer` section to you `webpack.config.js`.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver

In this section have a `contentBase` property specify where you want to serve your application from.

Then when you have done that you should be able to run `webpack-dev-server` and have it serve your application with your webpack bundled assets.

Comment: When I run webpack-dev-server I get: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version, and make sure you are using compatible versions of `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server`.